# Backup (Recover) SQL Server Database without SQL Services Running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backups, database-restore

We've had a harddrive on a PC go belly-up.  We were able to partially get it up and running, enough to get files off, but most of the services (including SQL-related services) cannot run.  Therefore, we cannot connect via Management Studio.

We do have a data backup, but it's a little old (it's a non-critical bunch of data).

Is there any way to restore a database on a new machine with just the database files?

Comment: There is some ambiguity with your statement "we do have a data backup". Is this the original DB files, or a .bak file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN for attaching a database (MDB File)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx)

1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
2. Right-click Databases and click Attach.
3. In the Attach Databases dialog box, to specify the database to be attached, click Add; and in the Locate Database Files dialog box, select the disk drive where the database resides and expand the directory tree to find and select the .mdf file of the database; for example: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf`
4. Optionally, to specify a different name for the database to attach as, enter the name in the Attach as column of the Attach Databases dialog box.
5. Optionally, change the owner of the database by selecting a different entry in the Owner column.
6. When you are ready to attach the database, click OK.

Comment: I had to do this last night after a DB corruption

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

Restore database dbnamegoeshere from disk='path to backup file here'

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the database files to another machine with SQL services running, and then attach them (right click on `Databases`, select `Attach...`)